# Will windows 8.1 app package from xamarin work for windows 10 tab?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have created an app package for Windows 8.1 for a Hello world app using XAMARIN to test whether it works for windows 10 Surface Pro or not. And it Doesn't.
I am using a Windows 8.1 OS with Visual studio 15 and one of my friend is using Windows 13. In both our cases, it doesn't work. We have the latest version of xamarin.

Since Windows apps have a forward compatibility, Why doesn't this package work for Windows 10.

Do I have to specifically have a Windows 10  OS to develop windows 10 app in xamarin?

I have had a look in the Xamarin docs but cannot find my answer. Please help with a brief explanation.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit regarding "And it Doesn't [work]"? I've built a Xamarin.Forms app on Windows 8.1, using a Windows 8.1 app, and it worked fine on Windows 10 machines. It's certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.you need windows 10 to develop windows 10 app in xamarin.and you must add UWP project not Window8.1 . UWP app will support in window 10 as well as others universal platform like windows 10 tablet also.

Comment: But my visual studio is upgraded to update 3 which gives all options of UWP app creation. When it allows to create apps for it, technically it should work in the tablet too!

Comment: yes you can create it .but i dont think you can run it without win10

Comment: Well, Then what is the use of creating the UWP app in Windows 8.1 if we already know that it will not work while installing it on windows 10?

Comment: it will work on windows 10 ofcourse thats why we need to  craeet it in win 10.you can use VM as of now for devlopment .

Comment: i dont have idea about upgraded vs as u said.it allows to create UWP in that. so can You build it and and run it?